# Is there a similar function to auto() of python in java

Tags: python, java, enums

```
from enum import Enum, auto
class language(Enum):
    Java = auto()
    Python = auto() 
print(list(language.Java.value))
```

it automaticly assigns a value to Java and Python

is there a similar method or a  way to do this in java

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in Java, but all enumerations derive from the class [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html). This class has a property `ordinal` which is a integer automatically assigned at creation:

For instance:

```
  public enum Language {
    JAVA,
    PYTHON
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (var value : Language.values()) {
      System.out.printf("%s : %d%n", value.name(), value.ordinal());
    }
  }
```

Will print:

```
JAVA : 0
PYTHON : 1
```